# Emit with key as zero in map reduce in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, morphia

Giving the value of the key as **0** in the emit functions and after reduce it correctly gives the total of a column in the collection as intended. Now my question is I don't understand how this is working.

I have my emit like this;

> **function(){ emit(0, this.total);** }

Could somebody please explain to me the working in this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapReduce is a tricky thing. You need to change your mindset to understand it. In your particular case, you told mongo that don't care about grouping options. When you emit like this, all your `this.total`'s will be sent to one batch with identifier **0** and aggregated all-together at reduce step. This also means that this cases are identical:

```
function(){ emit(0, this.total); }
function(){ emit(1, this.total); }
function(){ emit('asdf', this.total); }
function(){ emit(null, this.total); }
```

They will lead to save result, even batch name is different.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not able to find the mention of this in the mongo documentation. Can you provide a link to the actual documentation if you know?

Comment: [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)             [examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) [article 1](http://blog.serverdensity.com/map-reduce-and-mongodb/) [article 2](http://kylebanker.com/blog/2009/12/mongodb-map-reduce-basics/)

Answer (score 1):

To compliment the other answer with some internals, when you emit your single and only key the resulting document from the emit will look something like:

```
{_id:0,value:[5,6,7,8,9]}
```

With the array representing the combination of all the emits.

Emits grouped upon the key when you emit so this means there will only be one document with the content of that document being all the `total` fields in the collection.

So when the reduce comes along and you add all of these numbers together it will correctly sum up the total for all `total` fields in the collection.

Comment: Thanks Sammaye for the insight. Is there a documentation that I can actually look into for this? I have not been able to find one.

Comment: @nagaheadhunter It shows it a little in the reduce section of this article http://kylebanker.com/blog/2009/12/mongodb-map-reduce-basics/ but I ave been finding that 10gen have been taking out a lot of technical stuff from many posts and documentation pages so this is the best piece I can find on the actual internals of how it works

Comment: ok will look at it. Thanks. But as of now, we have refrained from using this due to lack of mention in the doc.